# Embedded quote in Quick Books Online API 3.0 Query

Tags: c#, .net, quickbooks-online

I am using the QickBooks Online API Version 3. I have dowloaded the nuget package for .net
I am trying to find a customer, by name, with an embedded quote in their name.
This returns an error. 
This code works for customers without an embedded quote.

How do I escape the quote so the query works? I have tried '' and \'
Or, Is there a different way that I can search for customers by name? e.g. a method on the Dataservice, or QueryService object

```
List<Customer> findCustomer = new List<Customer>();

String customerName = "Ruby's Diner";

String query = String.Format("Select * From Customer Where DisplayName='{0}'", customerName);

try
{
    QueryService<Customer> customerQueryService = new QueryService<Customer>(this.ServiceContext);
    findCustomer = customerQueryService.ExecuteIdsQuery(query).ToList();

}
```

Comment: Have you tried `Where DisplayName=\"{0}\""`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to escape single-quotes in Query Filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22185857/how-to-escape-single-quotes-in-query-filter)

Comment: I did try \"{0}\" it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following sample here-
https://gist.github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/6582149

Escaping with double slash in code will resolve this issue.