# Quickbooks api v3 filters quotation

Tags: vb.net, quickbooks

I have an item with name='9" Plate - Champagne' in quickbooks online.
but if I use method that I use its doesn't return anything and that's happens only with item name with quotation mark.

```
Dim ItemQueryService As New Intuit.Ipp.QueryFilter.QueryService(Of Intuit.Ipp.Data.Item)(context)
Dim q As String = "Select * from Item where Name = '9" Plate - Champagne'"
Dim Itemlist = ItemQueryService.ExecuteIdsQuery(q)
```

How to handle special quotation in this statement?

Comment: You can refer the following thread. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22517452/intuit-ipp-rest-api-query-string-escape/22528296#22528296

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The escape for the double quote is another double quote, so try:

```
Dim q As String = "Select * from Item where Name = '9"" Plate - Champagne'"
```

Edit: Hrmm..

Did you try:

```
Dim q As String = "Select * from Item where Name = '9\" Plate - Champagne'"
```

or

```
Dim q As String = "Select * from Item where Name = '9\"" Plate - Champagne'"
```

or

```
Dim q As String = "Select * from Item where Name = '9"""" Plate - Champagne'"
```

or

```
Dim q As String = "Select * from Item where Name = '9&quot; Plate - Champagne'"
```

or

```
Dim q As String = "Select * from Item where Name = '9%22 Plate - Champagne'"
```

Actually.. have you tried url-encoding the whole string?

```
Dim q As String = "Select%20*%20from%20Item%20where%20Name%20%3D%20%279%22%20Plate%20-%20Champagne%27"
```

Comment: Edited to add a few more things to try