# Intuit IPP Rest API query string escape

Tags: api, rest, intuit-partner-platform

So, for the [Intuit IPP Rest API](https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=V3QBO#Customer),

Say if i want to query a customer who's name is ABC, i can use a http get request like this

```
https://qb.sbfinance.intuit.com/v3/company/198445012/query?query=select Id from Customer where FullyQualifiedName%3D'ABC'
```

&3D is a url escape of '=',  this works without any problem.

Now if the customer's name is A&B,  I tried the query string like this

```
select Id from Customer where FullyQualifiedName='A&B'
```

After the url encoding, it looks like this

```
https://qb.sbfinance.intuit.com/v3/company/198445012/query?query=select Id from Customer where FullyQualifiedName%3D'A%26B'
```

It will fail.

Any Idea?

**Update**

The above urls i copied from the IPP's API explorer.

Here is the code,  I am using [DevDefined.OAuth](https://code.google.com/p/devdefined-tools/wiki/OAuth)

```
        IConsumerRequest conReq = _oSession.Request();
        conReq = conReq.Get();
        conReq.AcceptsType = "application/xml";
        //conReq = conReq.ForUrl(string.Format(@"https://qb.sbfinance.intuit.com/v3/company/{0}/query?query={1}", Settings.Default.QuickBooksOnlineRealmId, @"select * from Customer where DisplayName='ABC'"));   if use this line, it works fine
        conReq = conReq.ForUrl(string.Format(@"https://qb.sbfinance.intuit.com/v3/company/{0}/query?query={1}", Settings.Default.QuickBooksOnlineRealmId, @"select * from Customer where DisplayName='A&B'"));
        try
        {                
            string str = conReq.ReadBody();

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //ex.Message
        }
```

the returned xml data like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<IntuitResponse xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" time="2014-03-20T06:24:12.408-07:00">
  <Fault type="ValidationFault">
    <Error code="4000">
      <Message>Error parsing query</Message>
      <Detail>QueryParserError: Invalid content. Lexical error at line 1, column 44.  Encountered: &lt;EOF&gt; after : &quot;\'A&quot;</Detail>
    </Error>
  </Fault>
</IntuitResponse>
```

I am not 100% sure, yesterday when i test, it actually return something says the oauth failed.  But this is what I got this morning.

Actually, you can try it within IPP's API explorer, it gives the same result.

The devdefined's code for ForUrl

```
public static IConsumerRequest ForUrl(this IConsumerRequest request, string url)
{
    request.Context.RawUri = new Uri(url);
    return request;
}
```

That will encode the url as

```
https://qb.sbfinance.intuit.com/v3/company/1122502005/query?query=select%20*%20from%20Customer%20where%20DisplayName='A&B'
```

Ok, **finally**, found the issue:

The real issue is Uri(url) won't escape the & in 'A&B' because it doesn't know if it is a url & or part of the data,  So i changed the following line

```
conReq = conReq.ForUrl(string.Format(@"https://qb.sbfinance.intuit.com/v3/company/{0}/query?query={1}", Settings.Default.QuickBooksOnlineRealmId, @"select * from Customer where DisplayName='A&B'"));
```

as

```
conReq = conReq.ForUrl(string.Format(@"https://qb.sbfinance.intuit.com/v3/company/{0}/query?query={1}", Settings.Default.QuickBooksOnlineRealmId, Uri.EscapeDataString(@"select * from Customer where DisplayName='A&B'")));
```

use Uri.EscapeDataString to escape the data query string first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a customer with name 'A&B', then V3 service returns that customer object like below -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<IntuitResponse xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" time="2014-03-20T01:54:46.834-07:00">
    <Customer domain="QBO" sparse="false">
        <Id>10</Id>
        <SyncToken>0</SyncToken>
        <MetaData>
            <CreateTime>2014-03-20T01:54:46-07:00</CreateTime>
            <LastUpdatedTime>2014-03-20T01:54:47-07:00</LastUpdatedTime>
        </MetaData>
        <FullyQualifiedName>A&amp;B</FullyQualifiedName>
        <DisplayName>A&amp;B</DisplayName>
        <PrintOnCheckName>A&amp;B</PrintOnCheckName>
        <Active>true</Active>
        <Taxable>true</Taxable>
        <Job>false</Job>
        <BillWithParent>false</BillWithParent>
        <Balance>100.00</Balance>
        <BalanceWithJobs>100.00</BalanceWithJobs>
        <PreferredDeliveryMethod>Email</PreferredDeliveryMethod>
    </Customer>
</IntuitResponse>
```

To retrieve this object by name, you need to use the following query

```
SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE DisplayName = 'A&B'
```

**But** it needs to be url encoded like following

```
SELECT+*+FROM+Customer+WHERE+DisplayName+%3D+%27A%26B%27
```

Java code to achieve this -

```
Customer customer = GenerateQuery.createQueryEntity(Customer.class);
String query = select($(customer)).where($(customer.getDisplayName()).eq("A&B")).generate();
// Query output - SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE DisplayName = 'A&B'
String encodedUrl = URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8");
```

It works perfectly. (Devkit handles all these pretty well )

Hope this answers your qts.

Thanks

Comment: I updated the question with my actual code, I thought the devdefined handles the url encoding.  From the returned message, seems the & cause the issue, but still don't know how to fix it

Comment: I'm not sure how it works in dev-defined(most probably,you need to explicitly encode it). In the value clause, you've passed - %3D'A%26B'. You can see that single quote is not encoded. Please take care of that as I did while trying this query using java. You can use IPP's .net lib to make this call. https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0150_ipp_.net_devkit_3.0/query_filters#Queries. 
Devkit download link - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please see an example here to escape special chars-

```
using Intuit.Ipp.Core;
using Intuit.Ipp.Data;
using Intuit.Ipp.LinqExtender;
using Intuit.Ipp.QueryFilter;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


static class SampleCalls
{
public static Customer QueryCustomerByDisplayName(ServiceContext context, string     displayName)     {
displayName = displayName.Replace("'", "\\'"); //Escape special characters
QueryService<Customer> customerQueryService = new QueryService<Customer>(context);
return customerQueryService.Where(m => m.DisplayName == displayName).FirstOrDefault();
}
}
```